# How to write and save the values (array) in column by column using csv_write

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

with open('kp_insitu.csv', 'w', newline='') as myfile:

```
     for i in range(5):
        Arden # it is array of 100 elements
        wr = csv.writer(myfile,delimiter=',')
        for word in Arden:
            wr.writerow([word])
```

The values (5 arrays values) are printing continuous not column by column in csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fresh answer.

I had to guess what your "Arden" variable looks like.  It may be a one-dimensional sequence (list or tuple) of 100 values.

Your first problem is that you're breaking Arden apart with a for loop (line 4), and then writing each value **as its own row** as well as **wrapping each value inside a list** (line 5).  So, currently, you're getting a single **column** of values in the CSV file, am I correct?

Your second problem is not essential to fix, but you probably should.  Create one CSV Writer object and use it to process the whole file, instead of creating one CSV Writer object for each row of data (line 3).

Working code, based on my best guess of what you are trying to do:

```
import csv
filename = "test.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")
wr = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
for i in range(5):
    data = list(range(10*i, 10*i+9)) # one row of mock data
    wr.writerow(data)
f.close()
```

The file `test.csv` looks like this:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18
20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28
30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38
40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing much code, so I have to take some guesses.

It appears that you are creating the CSV writer object five separate times.  Is that what you want?  I think that you are overwriting your file repeatedly and that you should create it before entering the loop.

You also hide all the details of creating Arden.  Are you appending to the end of a growing object?  If you want five separate rows, you need to generate each row on its own.

Comment: As I mentioned, Arden is 100 value array and it generated after some calculations. from an input file, I will generate like this 5 Arden arrays that I need to write column by column.

Comment: So you generate 5 different arrays which are each one-dimensional, 1 x 100?  Did you try moving the third line of your code to the top as I suggested?  Is Arden initialized empty every time?

Comment: I am getting a different set of Arden values every time. when I am writing in a csv file it is saving all 5 array value continuously (1st array value take up to 100 lines and the second array value is starting at 101th line (which I want as next column) ).

Comment: I suspect that you may be preventing the CSV writers from issuing a line break because you create five different CSV write objects and you each have them only write one line.  Did you try moving the line which reads `wr = csv.writer(myfile,delimiter=',')` to line 1 as I suggested?

Comment: No. John, it is not working. is there any other method (one I was looking creating data frames columns)

Comment: I went ahead and entered your code with some assumptions about the structure of the data, which you are not specifying very clearly.  I will post a fresh answer so that I can type multiple paragraphs and paste multi-line code.  If it answers your questions, you can mark that one as your answer.